# Is there a javascript library to slugify strings into valid CSS class names?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for something that will turn 'some ugly #string' into 'some-ugly-string'. There are rules for valid CSS identifiers (ids and class names) and it'd be wonderful if that library followed those rules.

Comment: As far as I know, `some ugly #string` is in fact a valid identifier ;)

Comment: Strip out the characters you don't like and replace strings of whitespace with `-`. Sounds like a simple regular expression replacement; no need for a library.

Comment: @ComFreek: `some ugly #string` is unusable as a CSS identifier.  `"some ugly #string"` and `'some ugly #string'` are valid attribute values that you can use with `[]` expressions, but you can't expect CSS (or jQuery, or `querySelector`) to understand the identifier with sugary `#` and `.`.  Per the CSS standard (not the HTML standard) identifiers include alphanumerics, '-' and '_' where the first character is not a number and the first two characters are not '--' or '-' followed by a number.

Comment: @sqykly One can escape these characters, see here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: @ComFreek If you're writing it out manually, you're absolutely right.  Since OP is referring to replacing the invalid characters with a library, I assume that he would be using a regexp or library to escape them, too.  I can see where replacing with '-' might lead to name clashes if the system generating the identifiers is totally naive, e.g. "foo.*bar" vs "foo@bar", and inserting the escapes might be a better option.  The regexp would be (even) less readable, though.

Comment: I don't like escaping because it will look awful in the (S)CSS file. Slugs are fine, and if they clash they clash :P "You can make it foolproof, but you can't make it damn foolproof."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function identify(ugly) {
    var step1 = ugly.replace(/^[^-_a-zA-Z]+/, '').replace(/^-(?:[-0-9]+)/, '-');
    var step2 = step1 && step1.replace(/[^-_a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '-');
    return step2;
}
```

How about that?

edited: don't use the other one - it will work unless `ugly` starts with an invalid character.  This one will work for anything.  Also, I call this library `identifyUgly.js`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you!